# Warning: Undefined array key "id2"

Tags: php, post

Buen día compañeros :), espero estén bien. estaba realizando un delete en una tabla, con php y mysql. el asunto es que no me deja realizar el delete, revisando esto me da el error de undefined array key. no se por que me sale si el Id del input lo uso en más lados. ¿me podrían ayudar? cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

en esta parte esta el modal donde saco el id.

```
<form action="bajas.php" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalE" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Eliminar el elemento actual</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
        onclick="cancelar()" id="quita"></button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="">id</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="" id="id2" class="form-control"><br>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="cancelar()" 
        id="quitar">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="eliminar" onclick="adelante()" >eliminar datos</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

manda a llamar bajas.php

```
<?php
     

        #if (isset($id)) {
            include('db.php'); 
            $id = $_POST["id2"]; 
            echo "el id que estas mandando es : '$id'";

            $sentencia = "DELETE FROM producto WHERE Id ='$id'";  

            mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
           
    
            mysqli_close($conexion); 

            #header("Location: CRUD.php"); 
            #die();
        #}else{
          #  echo "hay problemas con el id "; 
        #} 
       
?>
```

el código de error que me sale es el siguiente.

Warning: Undefined array key "id2" in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevoP\php\bajas.php on line 6
el id que estas mandando es : ''

por favor si me pudieran ayudar. Se los agradecería mucho.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca en el name del input también el id2

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <label for="">id</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="id2" id="id2" class="form-control"><br>
  </div>
```

Y el echo debería ser sin las comillas simples

```
echo "el id que estas mandando es : $id";
echo "el id que estas mandando es :".$id;
```

Siempre deberías hacer un `print_r($_POST);` para ver que todo venga correcto del formulario.

Si la respuesta es la correcta recuerda marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: oh si!... ya le puse tambien el name al input y ya funciona muchas gracias :) y tambien ya cambie el echo gracias por la ayuda. en un momento marco la respuesta como correcta